# Response body not showing in Katalon Studio

Tags: soap, automated-tests, katalon-studio

I have started to use Katalon Studio for my Automated Tests. I am sending SOAP request and getting response status but unfortunately cannot see the response body in the Katalon Studio. Is there any way that I can see the response body?

[You can see screenshot from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbuw0.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with this. I referred here (http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?op=Add). I am getting the response body.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <intA>2</intA>
      <intB>3</intB>
    </Add>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks your reply. The operating system of my computer is Win7. That's the way, I can't see the response body. Now, I use win10  and there is not any problem.